# How to turn off 'expo-barcode-scanner' completely upon scan?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I've found a couple of similar questions to this one, but it seems people are just disabling the render, which doesn't actually turn off the camera and leads to high power consumption. I want to completely turn off the camera after a QR code scan.

If anyone knows how to do this could you write up a quick example that just has a button that completely turns off and on the camera associated with `expo-barcode-scanner`? I don't have issues catching the barcode scan event.

Comment: Unless there's something I don't understand about the barcode scanner implementation, simply navigating back from the screen that uses it should be enough to release the resources.

Comment: Even I'm looking for the same